# Lucene Spatial: Sorting by Distance

Tags: java, scala, sorting, lucene

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I can't get spatial sorting to work in Lucene Spatial (10.3), as documented in [SpatialExample.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_4x/lucene/spatial/src/test/org/apache/lucene/spatial/SpatialExample.java). Here's my code (Scala - but translates 1:1 into Java):

```
val searcher = placeSearcherManager.acquire()

val point = spatialCtx.makePoint(lat, lon)

val args =
  new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.Intersects,
    spatialCtx.makeCircle(lon, lat, 
    DistanceUtils.dist2Degrees(100, DistanceUtils.EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_KM)))

val filter = spatialStrategy.makeFilter(args)

val valueSource = spatialStrategy.makeDistanceValueSource(point)

// Here's what's supposed to set up distance sorting
val distanceSort = new Sort(valueSource.getSortField(false)).rewrite(searcher)

try {  
  val topDocs = searcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), filter, limit, distanceSort) 
  val scoreDocs = topDocs.scoreDocs

  // Print the results
  scoreDocs.foreach(scoreDoc => {
    val doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc)
    val docPoint = spatialCtx.readShape(doc.get(spatialStrategy.getFieldName())).asInstanceOf[Point]
    val distance = spatialCtx.getDistCalc().distance(args.getShape.getCenter, docPoint)
    val distanceKM = DistanceUtils.degrees2Dist(distance, DistanceUtils.EARTH_EQUATORIAL_RADIUS_KM)
    Logger.info("distance: " + distanceKM)
  })
} finally {
  placeSearcherManager.release(searcher)
}
```

When I run the query, results don't seem to be affected by the sorting at all:

```
[info] application - distance: 406.01578203364323
[info] application - distance: 327.67269076509876
[info] application - distance: 218.94951150657565
[info] application - distance: 251.37927074183852
[info] application - distance: 140.6570939383426
[info] application - distance: 460.47502999630586
[info] application - distance: 462.37676932762116
[info] application - distance: 489.49001138999256
[info] application - distance: 392.0773262500455
[info] application - distance: 227.8864179949065
```

Changing the sort order from ascending to descending has no effect either.  I can't see any difference between what I'm doing and the offical example (except the use of the [SearcherManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_3/core/index.html), but I've checked and that doesn't make a difference). Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the val point = spatialCtx.makePoint(lat, lon) call backwards, it should be lon, lat since it's expecting x/y ?

Answer (score 0):

Argh. Back to answering my own questions. In case someone stumbles across this again: the reason in my case was that my code used two different strategy objects for read and write - and those used different settings for the maxLevel parameter of the GeoHashPrefixTree. Never do that! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i was implement in lucene v6, my code below can sort from nearest and if you want to sort from farest change value in valueSource.getSortField(true)

```
        SpatialContext ctx = SpatialContext.GEO;
        String[] c = cord.split(",");
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(prms.getValue(c[0],true));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(prms.getValue(c[1], true));
        Point currPt = ctx.makePoint(Double.valueOf(lng), Double.valueOf(lat));
        
        SpatialPrefixTree grid = new GeohashPrefixTree(ctx, 22);
        SpatialStrategy strategy = new RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy(grid, "location");
        ValueSource valueSource = strategy.makeDistanceValueSource(currPt);

        Sort distanceSort = new Sort(valueSource.getSortField(false)).rewrite(searcher);
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(baseQuery, Integer.MAX_VALUE,distanceSort);
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = topDocs.scoreDocs;
```